# Proper way of delaying the loading of view until a web request or other long running task completes

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, xamarin.ios, webrequest

When doing a webrequest, or any other long running task, I should do it in a separate thread (let's call this thread B) so as not to block the UI. But what's the standard way to take action on the results once the task completes?

I've come up with these options so far:

1) Set up a custom event that fires in thread B when the request completes and that the main thread listen for and handles properly.

2) When the request completes make a InvokeOnMainThread  call from thread B.

3) Pass along a reference to the ViewController when starting thread B. And then when the web request completes take whatever action is needed on the viewcontroller in thread B itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the ThreadPool to carry out these requests.   This has the advantage that the runtime automatically adds and removes threads based on their usage and you do not have to manage their life cycle:

```
 class MyViewController : UIViewController {
     void PlusOne (string url, string username)
     {
          ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (delegate {
              var wc = new WebClient ();
              wc.UploadString (url, "+1");
              BeginInvokeOnMainThread (delegate { PlusOneDone (username); });


     void PlusOneDone (string username)
     {
           Console.WriteLine ("Plus one completed for {0}", username);
     }
 }
```

In this scenario, I use a couple of anonymous methods, by using nested anonymous methods (or lambdas), you can easily propagate the parameters (in this case "username") from the original thread that calls PlusOne" to the callback m

Comment: Can PlusOneDone in this example be used to make a new Thread.PoolQueueUserWorkItem call?

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to use the [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx) class which provides an higher level API (than `WebRequest` and `WebResponse`) and are easier to use properly (e.g. to minimize memory allocations, deal with different encoding...) and **also** provides several easy=to-use `Async` methods.

E.g. [`WebClient.DownloadStringAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202.aspx) method and [`WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.ondownloadstringcompleted.aspx) event.

Answer (score 1):

I usually call a method which runs on a seperate thread with a callback action.

```
void StartRequest(Uri url, Action<T> callback) {
    using (var ns = new NSAutoReleasePool ()){
        // Do some work
        callback(T);
    }
}
```

With the `callback(T)` having access to whatever you want to manipulate.

You can also look at the [documentation on threading](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/threading) TweetStation or [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) for examples of ASync callbacks.

Of course you can use delegates to the same end, or events etc... You are on the right track!